# I want to get all the SQL Server login details in a table

Tags: sql-server

I am running the below query to get the all the SQL Server roles assigned logins and database roles assigned logins to be inserted in a table.

Please help me

Query:

```
use Dbname
go

insert into NEW_Privileged_Login
     select * 
     from openquery([servername], 'SELECT Serverproperty(''Servername'') as [Instance Name], LoginName as [PrivilegedLogin] FROM syslogins where  sysadmin = 1')
```

Comment: So what's the problem? Did you receive an error, or...? Did you meant to limit it to the server role of sysadmin?

Comment: Not only sysadmin the other roles also I need to get, I got stuck querying...

Comment: I tried all the ways  but no luck

Comment: Ok, remove the `where sysadmin = 1`. Can you elaborate on how you got stuck? Are you looking at your current server or another server? Because if its not another server, openquery isn't needed

Comment: Did you try removing the where clause that says to return only the sysadmin roles?

Comment: Sir I need only the Server level assigned to the user's details, But if I remove the where condition I am getting all the roles in the server

Comment: This may help, since I'm confused as to what you want exactly: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22803/listing-the-existing-sql-server-logins-and-users

Comment: So, are you looking for any Login that has a default server role? Maybe, instead of `sysadmin = 1` try `1 IN (sysadmin,serveradmin,setupadmin,processadmin,diskadmin,dbcreator,bulkadmin)`

Comment: that is working, how can i  replicate the same for Db level permissions please help me sir

Comment: Using `OPENQUERY`? Not easily, as you need to loop through every database. You might be able to make dynamic SQL in there, but that is going to get REALLY messy (if someone else wants to try, go for it, but I'm not). Why can't you run these queries directly on the servers? What database roles are you looking for check for as well?

Comment: All the Db roles like ( owner,accessadmin,securityadmin, ddladmin,denydatareader,denydatawriter